# (C) Can't Insert New Node to Head

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct link{
    int numb;
    struct link *next;
};
typedef struct link linked;



int printlist(linked *input);
linked *addnewnode(linked *input, int a);



int main(){


    linked *head;
    linked link1, link2, link3;
    head=&link1;
    link1.numb=1;
    link2.numb=2;
    link3.numb=3;


    link1.next=&link2;
    link2.next=&link3;
    link3.next=NULL;
    head=addnewnode(head, 31);
    printlist(head);
}


int printlist(linked *input){
    linked *tamp=input;
    while(tamp!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", tamp->numb);
        tamp = tamp->next;
    }

}

linked  *addnewnode(linked *input, int a){
    linked *temp=malloc(sizeof(linked));
    temp->next=input;
    temp->numb=a;
    input=temp;
    return input;
}
```

OUTPUT= 1 2 3

Hey, Im kinda new to pointers and linked list stuff, I tried to insert a new node by changing head but it isn't working, I dont think it has something with listing, can you help me about the node insertion?

Comment: I run this code and get "31 1 2 3"

Comment: Your `addnewnode` is correct.  But, you probably do _not_ want: `linked link1, link2, link3;`. Instead, try: `linked *head = NULL; for (int i = 1;  i <= 3;  ++i) head = addnewnode(head,i);` Because `addnewnode` is pushing to the head/front of the list each time, when printing they will come out in reverse order.

Comment: The reason that I say that you probably don't want `link1` et. al. is because they are on the stack. And, `addnewnode` uses `malloc` to create a node on the heap. You want a list that is _consistent_ in the way it is created. Otherwise, when you write a function to free/destroy the list, you'll try to do `free` on something that is _not_ on the heap.

Comment: The code as such will work fine, and will keep inserting new nodes at the front and even print all the nodes. However, as @craig-estey mentions, it is good practice to always allocate memory on the heap for all the nodes.